# Could not create the java virtual machine via webstart

Tags: jvm, java

I have an application which is launched using Java Web Start.
Previously I used to launch this via IE 64bit and it worked fine, until Java decided to update to v7.
Then it went pear shaped.

This application doesn't work with Java 7, so I uninstalled and went back to Java 6_37 but now I can never launch it from the 64 bit browser. it always displays an error with "Java Virtual Machine Launcher - Could not create the Java virtual machine"

The 32 bit version of IE is fine, as is Chrome but not the 64 bit version.

I've dug through the registry to modify or eliminate any reference to jre7 and have used Revo but this only detected the JRE6 version I had.

Any help on how to get my 64 bit IE working would be much appreciated.

Machine is running Windows 7, 64 Bit.

Comment: Oh, why can't you run your J7 on J1.6 compatibility mode?

Comment: @BlessedGeek How do I set the 1.6 compatibility mode?

Answer (score 0):

Users should download 64-bit Java software, if they are running 64-bit browsers. For downloading 64-bit Java click [64-bit manual download](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp)

Comment: Hi Bhavik,I have the 64 bit version of java installed, JAVA_HOME is pointing to it and other apps I have use this when launched from the command line. The problem is with Javawebstart being launched from a 64bit browser..

Answer (score 0):

No longer an issue, from memory it was because I had an older version of the 32bit jvm which IE was pointing to.
Once I uninstalled JAVA completely and re-installed it got the correct 64bit version.